# Nginx HTTP(2) "Waiting" Time on Connections

Tags: apache, caching, nginx, https, http2

We are new to optimizing nginx and are learning a lot about it.

We are running nginx on OS X (nginx/1.9.9).

We are running it in a caching proxy mode with an Apache server behind the nginx box.  Images and static content are cached on nginx while page requests are forwarded to the Apache server.

We confirm we are hitting the cache for static content with "X-Cache HIT" headers.

However, when running one of the sites through GT Metrix, we noticed there is a long "waiting" time on the HTTP(2) connection.

Please see this screenshot as an example of what we mean:
[image]

Notice the 500msec wait time.

Now, is this wait time on the server side or client side?  Could it be because HTTP(2) is waiting on the previous files to load first?  I know it pipelines resources, one-by-one I believe unlike HTTP1/1 where the browser opens up multiple individual connections.

Also, notice the content from pagead2.google.com and secure.gravatar.com has almost no "wait" time.

Some information from the nginx config:

```
worker_processes  auto;

events {
worker_connections  2048;
multi_accept        on;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on why we have these high "waiting" times?  Am I worrying for no reason and it's a normal part of HTTP2?

Thanks for your suggestions, advice and insight in advance.

Comment: What makes you think GT Metrix is connecting to your site via HTTP/2 ?

Comment: Because the headers show so.

Answer (score 1):

Given the other values shown in your screenshot, I would guess your throughput is limited by network latency between GT Metrix endpoint and your server.

HTTP/2 is running on top of TCP and thus is limited by things such as **TCP slow start** which means that transferring data requires several round trips between your server and GT Metrix. When your latency is about 100ms as seems likely from your limited trace, data transfers take much longer no matter the bandwidth available.

You can easily test this assumption by running another GT Metrix test with a test server closer to your actual server (fwiw, the request takes 55ms from my desktop)